# ROC curve for cross-validated Matlab SVM

Tags: matlab, svm, cross-validation

I need to plot a ROC curve for SVM classifier, following the many threads about the topic and matlab examples, I did like the following

```
mdlSVM = fitcsvm(pred,resp,'Standardize',true);
mdlSVM = fitPosterior(mdlSVM);
[~,score_svm] = resubPredict(mdlSVM);
[Xsvm,Ysvm,Tsvm,AUCsvm] = perfcurve(resp,score_svm(:,mdlSVM.ClassNames),'true');
```

So far, so good, I also cross-validated 3-folds my model.

```
mdlSVM = fitcsvm(pred,resp,'Standardize',true,'Kfold',3);
```

At this point the `resubPredict` function throws an error saying that it doesn't take crossvalidated model.

How can I plot the ROC curve for my cross-validated SVM classifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kfoldPredict` does the job quite well .

https://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationpartitionedmodel.kfoldpredict.html